# PostgreSQL - Tuning work_mem and max_connections

Tags: postgresql

I am using [PGTune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/) to help tune my web application using PostgreSQL 9.5

Some background - The web app is a real estate search site, with up to 200 active users during the day performing fairly complex location-based queries.  GeoDjango is used to host the site.

My question is about tuning `work_mem` and `max_connections`.  In PGTune, I noticed that when I increase `max_connections`, the recommended `work_mem` decreases.  I had several questions in mind:

1. As a rule of thumb, should you keep `max_connections` as low as possible, to allow for more `work_mem` to be freed up for better performance for each individual query?
2. For a website with up to 200 active users at a time, constantly performing queries - what number of `max_connections` I should have?
3. I currently have my `max_connections` set to 500 and the recommended `work_mem` by PGTune is 8388kB.  Is it worth reducing `max_connections` to 400 or maybe 300, which allows me to increase `work_mem`?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that when I increase max_connections, the recommended
>   work_mem decreases

PGTune assumes that if more connections are open, then there will be more queries running simultaneously, and then more multiple of `work_mem` are likely to be allocated, but such allocations happen on the fly. In practice it depends on what the queries sent to the database will do, which PGTune can't know. There is no hard dependency between `max_connections` and `work_mem`.

Since your database is already running in production, you can know much better than PGTune how to tune it by observing it.

Do the queries use temporary storage on disk? Monitor `temp_files` and `temp_bytes` in [pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW). If they don't, you don't need to increase `work_mem` anyway.

Does the server has lots of free memory? If it does, you can increase `work_mem` without caring about `max_connections`.

How much connections do you actually have (`select count(*) from pg_stat_activity`) compared to `max_connections`? If you're close to the limit and you're reducing it, your apps will fail to connect.